# Vulnerabilities not fixed installing charts.js and ng2-charts update in Angular 13

Tags: angular, npm, charts, angular13, ng2-charts

I'm trying to update chart.js and ng2-charts in Angular 13 but when I install: npm i chart.js@3.7.1 and npm i ng2-charts@3.0.1 I get this vulnerabilities I can't solve with nmp audit fix, Do I need to update any other dependencies in this cases?

```
up to date, audited 1685 packages in 5s

187 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

# npm audit report

@angular/core  <11.0.5
Severity: moderate
Cross site scripting in Angular - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-c75v-2vq8-878f
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install codelyzer@0.0.28, which is a breaking change
node_modules/codelyzer/node_modules/@angular/core
  codelyzer  >=1.0.0-beta.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of @angular/core
  node_modules/codelyzer

lodash  <=4.17.20
Severity: critical
Prototype Pollution in lodash - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-jf85-cpcp-j695
Regular Expression Denial of Service (ReDoS) in lodash - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-x5rq-j2xg-h7qm
Prototype Pollution in lodash - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-p6mc-m468-83gw
Prototype Pollution in lodash - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-fvqr-27wr-82fm
Command Injection in lodash - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-35jh-r3h4-6jhm
No fix available
node_modules/karma-html-reporter/node_modules/lodash
  karma-html-reporter  *
  Depends on vulnerable versions of lodash
  node_modules/karma-html-reporter

terser  5.0.0 - 5.14.1
Severity: high
Terser insecure use of regular expressions before v4.8.1 and v5.14.2 leads to ReDoS - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-4wf5-vphf-c2xc
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/terser
  @angular-devkit/build-angular  0.1001.0-next.0 - 12.2.17 || 13.0.0-next.0 - 13.3.8 || 14.0.0-next.0 - 14.1.0-rc.3
  Depends on vulnerable versions of terser
  node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular

trim-newlines  <3.0.1
Severity: high
Uncontrolled Resource Consumption in trim-newlines - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-7p7h-4mm5-852v
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/dateformat/node_modules/trim-newlines
  meow  3.4.0 - 5.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of trim-newlines
  node_modules/dateformat/node_modules/meow

8 vulnerabilities (3 moderate, 4 high, 1 critical)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

To address all issues possible (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.
```

Answer (score 2):

Most of npm "vulnerabilities" can be simply ignored.

I recommend you to read this article: https://overreacted.io/npm-audit-broken-by-design/

Comment: Pleas use comments for this type of suggestions.